# ORA-00937: not a single-group group function using a Subquery in a SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to capture the total length of a few fields which make up a file path.  **t2.path1** and **t2.path2** are related, however the **column1** length does not relate.  I am trying to perform the following query which returns the

```
**ORA-00937: not a single-group group function**
```

error when it runs.  The same query works in MSSQL.

Is there any way with to perform this query?

```
SELECT
  SUM(LENGTH(t2.path1) + LENGTH(t2.path2) + (SELECT LENGTH(column1) FROM table1 WHERE uniqueid = 13)) AS "File Path Length"
FROM table2 t2
```

Thanks!

Comment: That query [doesn't get that error](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/88e7e/1), which isn't helpful for diagnosing what is wrong.

Comment: @AlexPoole Good catch, didn't think on testing the query. Op, post the whole query you are using, not one that actually works

Comment: Odd, I was playing with the query for a while prior to posting it and it didn't work.  Now I'm in a new session and didn't have a problem.  Thanks for your help and sorry to waste any ones time.

Comment: I got it, the problem comes out when you try to use a display column in the select (ie SELECT t2.path1 , SUM(...) FROM ... ).  Other posts mention using GROUP BY, but that doesn't appear to work either.

Comment: @Pheathers - adding the same column to the select list and the group by works. [What are you doing differently](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/88e7e/3)?

Comment: @AlexPoole, I was attempting to use GROUP BY 1 instead of the column name.  When I substituted the column name (or more specifically the columns), it worked.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Right, you can only use positional notation (or column aliases) in an order-by clause.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a `CROSS JOIN` to get the result from `table1` instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(t2.path1)+LENGTH(t2.path2)+LENGTH(t1.column1)) AS "File Path Length"
FROM table2 t2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * 
            FROM table1
            WHERE uniqueid = 13) t1
```